# Query takes a very long time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a query that I am trying to execute at the moment but after letting it load for a few minutes I am thinking there is probably something I am doing wrong.

Here is what I am trying to execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM open_hours
INNER JOIN open_times
    ON open_hours.id = open_times.open_hour_id
INNER JOIN off_peak_times
    ON open_hours.id = off_peak_times.open_hour_id;
```

I have three tables:

open_hours:

Roughly 14k rows

```
id;
owner_type;
owner_id;
seats;
time_interval;
max_at_one_time;
created_at;
updated_at;
minutes_in_advance;
```

open_times:

Roughly 18k rows

```
id;
open_hour_id;
time_start;
time_end;
weekday;
created_at;
meal_type;
```

off_peak_times:

Roughly 10k rows

```
id;
open_hour_id;
time;
discount;
seats;
created_at;
updated_at;
weekday;
```

I have tried reducing the SELECT * to a SELECT open_hours.id, open_times.meal_type since in reality that's the only number I'm trying to get right now. It gets me the results in roughly 30 seconds, which still sounds like a lot to me.

I run other queries on other tables that are a lot bigger and yet get results almost instantly, so is there something that I am missing or not considering?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan to see what it says about the query? It may suggest indexes that will improve performance, or hint at ways the query could be optimized.

Comment: I would think this is the best you're going to get it. You could look into using a cross apply instead of a join, but I don't know if that would help... You could also increase the DTUs/Performance tier of the database itself

Comment: @KenWhite I haven't, because I don't know what an "execution plan" is hahaha. MySQL / SQL beginner here. Going to Google that now.

Comment: @james5 ok thanks, going to look up "cross apply" now and what that means haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the query faster in your case there have three things you can do.
Don't know it will help you or not but According to SQL optimizing query concepts, it must help.

1. Create `CLUSTERED INDEX` for all your tables. Cluster index makes the `SELECT` query faster at 30:70 of ratio.
2. You should make column list instead of STAR statement (avoid `SELECT *`). Extra columns make BUFFER-POOL heavy.
3. You can use VIEW instead of the query. Because VIEW during JOIN statements is better than the normal query.

From above all of three, you must try first option (CLUSTER INDEX), which will really improve performance.
Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Run this

Alter table open_times add index(open_hour_id);

Alter table off_peak_times add index(open_hour_id);

Then run your query again. These are small enough tables, i would not worry about reading a bunch right now about your execution plan. I think you will find this speeds it up.

Answer (score 0):

For a further analysis it is important to know the query behavior and table information. This is possible executing the statements below:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM open_hours INNER JOIN open_times ON open_hours.id = open_times.open_hour_id INNER JOIN off_peak_times ON open_hours.id = off_peak_times.open_hour_id\G
SHOW WARNINGS \G
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM open_hours INNER JOIN open_times ON open_hours.id = open_times.open_hour_id INNER JOIN off_peak_times ON open_hours.id = off_peak_times.open_hour_id\G           -- MYSQL 5.6+ only
```

Additionally, for each unique table involved:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM <db> LIKE '<tablename>' \G 
SHOW INDEXES FROM <db>.<tablename> \G 
SHOW CREATE TABLE <db>.<tablename> \G
```

Comment: So... I'm reading the result of your suggested query, and I'm not sure what I'm looking at, so I'm assuming this is where I'm supposed to start reading this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Basically, we are trying to understand what MySQL is executing behind the curtains to retrieve your data. We want to check if the necessary indexes exist for example.

Comment: So would you like me to publish the result of those commands here?

Comment: Yes you can paste the result here and then it will be possible to identify the bottleneck that you are facing.

Comment: I'm going to skip that since I tried the solution given by these other guys and it seems to be doing the trick for now . But thanks! I'll read more about those