# my query is taking too 10 seconds to execute how to reduce time and its having many subqueries how to over come this

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SELECT        
    p.ID, p.EMAIL, 
    'Sales : ' + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + coordinator
                        FROM tbl_clientCoordinators l
                        WHERE type = 'SALES' AND p.ID = l.client_ID 
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + ' |  ' + 'R.M : ' + 
            ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + coordinator
                          FROM tbl_clientCoordinators l
                          WHERE type = 'RELATIONSHIP MANAGER' AND p.ID = l.client_ID 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 'N/A') + ' |  ' + 'P.O : ' + 
            ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + coordinator
                          FROM tbl_clientCoordinators l
                          WHERE type = 'PROCESSING OFFICER' AND p.ID = l.client_ID 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 'N/A') + ' |  ' + 'P.C : ' + 
            ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + coordinator
                          FROM tbl_clientCoordinators l
                          WHERE type = 'PROCESSING CONSULTANT' AND p.ID = l.client_ID 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 'N/A') + ' |  ' + 'P.M : ' + 
            ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + coordinator
                          FROM tbl_clientCoordinators l
                          WHERE type = 'PROCESSING MANAGER' AND p.ID = l.client_ID 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 'N/A') + ' |  ' + 'A.C : ' + 
            ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + coordinator
                          FROM tbl_clientCoordinators l
                          WHERE type = 'ASSISTANT CONSULTANT' AND p.ID = l.client_ID 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 'N/A') AS Cordinators
FROM
    tbl_client p
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an index to the `type` column

Comment: Also run it through sql query analyzer, that should give you an idea of whats going on

Comment: Why tag `c#`? . .

Comment: thank you reply i dint tried index for type. i dont how to do that please tell me how to do and by using c# i am executing this query

Comment: @3dd Query Analyser is the name of one of the SQL Server 2000 precursors to SSMS (along with Enterprise Manager). It is not a tool that analyses queries and tells you what is going on.

Comment: this answer may help you [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919848/query-takes-a-very-long-time-to-execute/50920611#50920611)

Comment: This question is lazy, its also a woefully bad query. The question lacks basic information, or any attempt to identify the bottle-necks and has a fix-my-codez attitude... Downvote Close

Answer (score 0):

Seems trying to do multiple things for simplicity. You should have join with tbl_clientCoordinators and then should have case based on type.

In case you fall to 4 condition then your query is joining data for 4 times. It should be 1 time

```
SELECT        
    p.ID, p.EMAIL, 
    'Sales : ' + ', ' + cco.coordinator + ' | ' + 
    (CASE cco.type WHEN  'SALES'  THEN 'R.M : ' 
                  WHEN  'RELATIONSHIP MANAGER' THEN 'P.O : '
                  WHEN  'PROCESSING OFFICER' THEN 'P.C : '
                  WHEN  'PROCESSING CONSULTANT' THEN 'P.M : '
                  WHEN  'PROCESSING MANAGER' THEN 'A.C : '
                  WHEN 'ASSISTANT CONSULTANT' THEN 'N/A'
    END) AS Cordinators
FROM
    tbl_client p
INNER JOIN tbl_clientCoordinators cco on cco.client_ID = p.ID
```

Comment: thank you sir but i dint clear about that please elaborate

Comment: i have did like this but i am not getting correct output

Comment: p.ID, p.EMAIL,
case 
when l.type = 'SALES' AND p.ID = l.client_ID then 'Sales :'+ l.COORDINATOR+''
when l.type = 'RELATIONSHIP MANAGER' AND p.ID = l.client_ID then 'R.M:'+ l.COORDINATOR+''
when l.type = 'PROCESSING OFFICER' AND p.ID = l.client_ID then 'P.O:'+ l.COORDINATOR+''
when l.type = 'PROCESSING CONSULTANT' AND p.ID = l.client_ID then 'P.C:'+ l.COORDINATOR+''
when l.type = 'PROCESSING MANAGER' AND p.ID = l.client_ID then 'P.M:'+ l.COORDINATOR+''
when l.type = 'ASSISTANT CONSULTANT' AND p.ID = l.client_ID then 'A.C:'+ l.COORDINATOR+''
end as COORDINATORS

Comment: from tbl_clientCoordinators l INNER JOIN
dbo.tbl_Client p ON p.ID = l.CLIENT_ID